# Creating a live web app

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts, xampp, webserver

I have to make an application which dynamically updates data using Highcharts. That wasn't a big problem because they have a good tutorial. And the example works fine.

When I wan't to share this application across multiple device (using xampp), I have some problems. When I open the link to my webapp:

```
http://IP-adress/ENRGYMONITOR/index.html
```

The graph shows up, but the no data is displayed or updated. Here is the javascript I wrote:

```js
var chart; // global
/**
* Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
*/
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/live-server-data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 5000);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });
});
```

Can anyone let me know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call is failing:

```
url: 'http://localhost/live-server-data.php'
```

"localhost" here would be the computer running the client (the web browser), not the server sending the data.

You should try to avoid an absolute URL.  Modify it to just:

```
 url: 'live-server-data.php'
```

**assuming** (this is important) that `live-server-data.php` is in the same directory as `index.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sloved my problem.